# Sort the array or the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have this line of code:

```
sourceRange = wbkSourceFile.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lengthOfArray, widthOfArray))
```

It should take a range from a worksheet that I am feeding into a macro and put it into an array so I can do some calculations and then place the resulting data on another sheet.  If I need that data to be sorted by three columns in the source data in order to do the calculations is it better to do the sorts on the sheet before copying the range to the array (ie running the above code) or fill the array and then sort the data?

In short is it better to sort the worksheet data and then load the array or just sort the array afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference is that if you do the sort the source sheet will end up sorted.  If the sub does the sort, the source sheet can be left un-changed.

Also if you are going to repeat this process a lot, having the sub do the sort will save you some time each time the data is processed.

Comment: But is there even a way to sort an array on three of the columns?  I don't think quick sort algorithm can do that.  My only remaining question is can I do a worksheet sort in code behind?

Comment: @VinnyGuitara  with code you can sort by any number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

vba doesn't have any inbuilt sorting functions, so if you were to do it with code you'd have to write/find a sorting algorithm. This will get very complicated if you're sorting on multiple columns. As such, I'd say your best bet would be to use Range.Sort to sort the data within the workbook.